# Specifying blob encoding in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, encoding, fileapi

The following code (vendor normalized) works perfectly fine and displays "➀➁➂ Test" in Firefox 8, but displays "âž€âžâž‚ Test" in Google Chrome. Is there any way to preserve encoding of blobs in Google Chrome short of writing a file to a temporary filesystem using the filesystem API?

```
var b = new Blob(["➀➁➂ Test"], {type: "text/plain;charset=UTF-8"});
var url = URL.createObjectURL(b);
open(url);
```

Comment: Have you tried declaring the encoding in head tag? http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/web/tips/declare.html

Comment: Appending a meta element in the resulting document doesn't do anything after the fact, and it's not possible to append <?xml encoding=...?> processing instructions to a text/plain document as they generate non-XML documents of type text/html. Even if I could, I doubt it would affect the encoding of the document after it's already loaded.

Comment: Firefox 8? Is that a nightly build? Have you tried it in the stable Firefox 5?

Comment: Firefox 5 doesn't have BlobBuilder.

Answer (score 26):

`new Blob(["➀➁➂ Test"])` will generate a Blob representing that text encoded as UTF-8.

That browsers assumes text files should be read in ISO is a weird choice IMM.

Appending the `{ type: "text/plain;charset=utf8" }` should generate the proper `Content-Type` header when they browsers will serve it through a blob URI. That Chrome doesn't with `open()` sounds like a bug.

Now you can workaround this by prepending a BOM sequence at the beginning of your text file, so that Chrome detects it as UTF, even without *Content-Type* info:

```
var BOM = new Uint8Array([0xEF,0xBB,0xBF]);
var b = new Blob([ BOM, "➀➁➂ Test" ]);
var url = URL.createObjectURL(b);
open(url);
```

```js
var BOM = new Uint8Array([0xEF,0xBB,0xBF]);

var blob_BOM = new Blob([ BOM, "➀➁➂ Test" ]);
var url_BOM = URL.createObjectURL(blob_BOM);
// for demo we also create one version without BOM
var blob_noBOM = new Blob([ "➀➁➂ Test" ]);
var url_noBOM = URL.createObjectURL(blob_noBOM);

document.querySelector('.BOM').href = url_BOM;
document.querySelector('.no-BOM').href = url_noBOM;

// to check whether they contain the same data, apart from the BOM
(async() => {
  const buf_BOM = await blob_BOM.slice(3).arrayBuffer(); // remove BOM sequence
  const buf_noBOM = await blob_noBOM.arrayBuffer();
  
  console.log( 'with BOM text data:' );
  console.log( JSON.stringify( [...new Uint8Array( buf_BOM )] ) );
  console.log( 'without BOM text data:' );
  console.log( JSON.stringify( [...new Uint8Array( buf_noBOM )] ) );

})();
```

```html
<a class="BOM">open file with BOM</a><br>
<a class="no-BOM">open file without BOM</a>
```

Comment: This is the perfect solution and I also use the trick to generate my UTF8+BOM CSV file so Excel can recognize as UTF-8 file.

Comment: The reason ISO-8859-1 is the default charset can be found in the 25 year old HTTP 1.1 standard, released in 1997. At that time UTF-8 had not yet got widespread use. At that time we still used *code-pages* that defined 256 characters. At that time ISO-8859-1 mad sense.

Answer (score 13):

Gecko (Firefox), WebKit (Safari, Chrome) and Opera support the non-standard `btoa` function for encoding a string in base 64. In order to get a base 64 string containing a string encoded as UTF-8 you need to use the `encodeURIComponent`-`unescape` trick. `encodeURIComponent` encodes a string as UTF-8 URL but `unescape` decodes each `%xx` as a single character. `btoa` expects a binary string of whatever encoding you want.

```
var base64 = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(data)));
window.open("data:text/plain;charset=UTF-8;base64,"+base64,"UTF-8 Text");
```

Of course this does not work in IE, but I think IE 10 will support the `Blob`-API. Who knows how it will handle encodings.

PS: IE seems not to be able to `window.open` data:-urls and would have a ridiculous small url length limitation anyway.

PPS: This works for me in Chrome:

```
var b = new Blob(["➀➁➂ Test"],{encoding:"UTF-8",type:"text/plain;charset=UTF-8"});
var url = URL.createObjectURL(b);
window.open(url,"_blank","");
```

Comment: In Chrome 34, this only works if the default encoding (settings/Customize fonts/Encoding) is set to "Unicode (UTF-8)". Seems like it currently ignores the ";charset=UTF-8" part :(

Comment: @kolypto Fixed the last code example by adding encoding option.

Comment: @kolypto But for me it worked without that option anyway. I use Linux and Linux's system encoding is UTF-8. So maybe Chrome *does* ignore these properties and just uses the system encoding and it happens to be UTF-8 for me. (I think one shouldn't us an OS that doesn't use UTF-8 as it's system encoding anyway.)

Comment: does not work for me anyway, and yes, I'm also Linux :) Here's how it looks like: http://i.imgur.com/Gxt0sae.jpg

Comment: @kolypto Strange system you got there where the default encoding in your browser isn't UTF-8. It's like that on my system: http://i.imgur.com/1YGGPU3.png I did not change this setting in Chrome. My `$LANG` is: de_AT.UTF-8

Comment: But anyway, you are right. When the default encoding is ISO-8859-1 then the text is broken. That should not be. So I guess one would have to generate HTML (with `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>`) to view that correctly in Chrome. If you just want to view stuff it is better to do that with HMTL anyway. If you want to trigger a download create an invisible `<a download="filename.txt">` and `.click()` it. (Should work in Chrome and Firefox. Firefox has some restrictions on this though.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the default page encoding for new tabs in Chrome. When the new window opens (after `window.open(url)`) choose View > Encoding > Unicode from the Chrome menu. This changed the displayed text from "âž€âžâž‚ Test" to "➀➁➂ Test" for me in Chrome 13.

If you want a solution that will let you open blobs in new windows regardless of the default encoding, then you can rely on the fact that a document in an iframe will inherit the parent document encoding when it doesn't explicitly specify its own encoding. So you can open a window with a blank HTML document served with a `Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8` header, then append an iframe to the body with the `src` attribute set to the blob URL.