# How to convert a string to file with UTF-32LE encoding in JS?

Tags: javascript, file, blob, utf-32

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672834/specifying-blob-encoding-in-google-chrome) thread I tried to create a blob with utf 32 encoding and BOM of FF FE 00 00(UTF-32LE representation) as follows:

```
var BOM = new Uint8Array([0xFF,0xFE,0x00,0x00]);
var b = new Blob([ BOM, "➀➁➂ Test" ]);
var url = URL.createObjectURL(b);
open(url);
```

But the file content gets corrupted and gets changed to a different language. What is the correct way to convert a string to a file with utf-32le format?

Edit:
Im trying this in browser environment

Comment: In what environment? A browser? Node.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: I'm assuming you're doing this in a browser, since you used Blob and Node.js only recently got Blob support, and you referenced a question doing this in a browser.

You're just setting the BOM, you're not handling converting the *data*. As it says in [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob), any strings in the array will be encoded using UTF-8. So you have a UTF-32LE BOM followed by UTF-8 data.

Surprisingly (to me), the browser platform doesn't seem to have a general-purpose text encoder ([`TextEncoder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder) just encodes UTF-8), but JavaScript strings provide a means of iterating through their code points (not just code units) and getting the actual Unicode code point value. (If those terms are unfamiliar, my blog post [*What is a string?*](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/01/26/what-is-a-string/) may help.) So you can get that number and convert it into four little-endian bytes. [`DataView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView) provides a convenient way to do that.

Finally, you'll want to specify the charset in the blob's MIME type (the BOM itself isn't sufficient). I expected `text/plain; charset=UTF-32LE` to work, but it doesn't, at least not in Chromium browsers. There's probably some legacy reason for that. `text/html` works (on its own), but we may as well be specific and do `text/html; charset=UTF-32LE`.

See comments:

```
function getUTF32LEUrl(str) {
    // The UTF-32LE BOM
    const BOM = new Uint8Array([0xFF,0xFE,0x00,0x00]);
    // A byte array and DataView to use when converting 32-bit LE to bytes;
    // they share an underlying buffer
    const uint8 = new Uint8Array(4);
    const view = new DataView(uint8.buffer);
    // Convert the payload to UTF-32LE
    const utf32le = Array.from(str, (ch) => {
        // Get the code point
        const codePoint = ch.codePointAt(0);
        // Write it as a 32-bit LE value in the buffer
        view.setUint32(0, codePoint, true);
        // Read it as individual bytes and create a plain array of them
        return Array.from(uint8);
    }).flat(); // Flatten the array of arrays into one long byte sequence
    // Create the blob and URL
    const b = new Blob(
        [ BOM, new Uint8Array(utf32le)],
        { type: "text/html; charset=UTF-32LE"} // Set the MIME type
    );
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(b);
    return url;
}
```

Beware, though, that [the specification "prohibits" browsers from supporting UTF-32](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#character-encodings) (either LE or BE) for HTML:

> **13.2.3.3 Character encodings**
>
> User agents must support the encodings defined in Encoding, including, but not limited to, UTF-8, ISO-8859-2, ISO-8859-7, ISO-8859-8, windows-874, windows-1250, windows-1251, windows-1252, windows-1254, windows-1255, windows-1256, windows-1257, windows-1258, GBK, Big5, ISO-2022-JP, Shift_JIS, EUC-KR, UTF-16BE, UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE/LE, and x-user-defined. User agents must not support other encodings.
>
> **Note:** The above prohibits supporting, for example, CESU-8, UTF-7, BOCU-1, SCSU, EBCDIC, and UTF-32. This specification does not make any attempt to support prohibited encodings in its algorithms; support and use of prohibited encodings would thus lead to unexpected behavior. [CESU8] [UTF7] [BOCU1] [SCSU]

You might be better off with one of the UTF-16s, given that you're using `window.open` to open the result. (For downloading, UTF-32 is fine if you really want a UTF-32 file.)

---

Sadly, Stack Snippets won't let you open a new window, but here's a full example you can copy and paste to run locally:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <title>UTF-32 Conversion</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png">
    <style>
    body, html {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    *, *:before, *:after {
        box-sizing: inherit;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Open" id="open">
<input type="button" value="Download" id="download">
<script type="module">
function getUTF32LEUrl(str, mimeType) {
    // The UTF-32LE BOM
    const BOM = new Uint8Array([0xFF,0xFE,0x00,0x00]);
    // A byte array and DataView to use when converting 32-bit LE to bytes;
    // they share an underlying buffer
    const uint8 = new Uint8Array(4);
    const view = new DataView(uint8.buffer);
    // Convert the payload to UTF-32LE
    const utf32le = Array.from(str, (ch) => {
        // Get the code point
        const codePoint = ch.codePointAt(0);
        // Write it as a 32-bit LE value in the buffer
        view.setUint32(0, codePoint, true);
        // Read it as individual bytes and create a plain array of them
        return Array.from(uint8);
    }).flat(); // Flatten the array of arrays into one long byte sequence
    // Create the blob and URL
    const b = new Blob(
        [ BOM, new Uint8Array(utf32le)],
        mimeType // Set the MIME type
    );
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(b);
    return url;
}
document.getElementById("open").addEventListener("click", () => {
    const str = "➀➁➂ Test";
    const url = getUTF32LEUrl(str, { type: "text/html; charset=UTF-32LE" });
    window.open(url);
});
document.getElementById("download").addEventListener("click", () => {
    const str = "➀➁➂ Test";
    const url = getUTF32LEUrl(str, { type: "text/plain; charset=UTF-32LE" });
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    a.download = "utf-32_file.txt";
    a.href = url;
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The BOM should be enough for a text/plain. I lack time to investigate your snippet right now, but setting the `Content-Type` to `text/html` alone is enough for it to be parsed correctly. `text/plain; charset=UTF-32LE` is read as UTF-16. Sounds like there is a bit of magic coming from `text/html` here.

Comment: @Kaiido - It would be in most file-based environments, yeah. Browsers be fun. :-) My first attempt was with `text/plain; charset=UTF-32LE` and I was surprised to find it didn't work. I figure as long as we're specifying the MIME type, it may as well include the charset.

Comment: Really weird and I must admit this goes beyond my current knowledge... If you try to set some HTML markup in `str` it will still be read as plain text, not as HTML. And if you serve it as plain/text browsers will read it as UTF-16... Might be noted that officially UTF32 [is not supported by the web platforms](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#character-encodings) (TextDecoder et al. never supported it). What are browsers doing here though is quite a mystery for me...

Comment: @Kaiido - Oh wow, that link is surprising, I would have expected UTF-32 to be supported. I wonder why it isn't. (`TextEncoder` doesn't even support the other supported encodings, just UTF-8.)

Comment: TextEncoder used to support the other "supported" encodings, but I think they've been removed in an attempt to get *one encoding to rule them all*. If needed [Joshua Bell's polyfill](https://github.com/inexorabletash/text-encoding) still does that. And according to https://crbug.com/417850#c5 UTF-32 has been "especially discouraged" because it "is rarely used, and frequently implemented incorrectly". And indeed, looking at both that bug or the FF one that's linked in #c1 it seems that browsers had bug with it, and I only ever met an UTF-32 file while writing tests for encodings stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Kaiido - embarrassingly, I thought you *had* linked to the multipage version because "Multipage Version" was bigger than the other boxes during the wait. I thought it was weird it was taking so long. :-D

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you for providing such a thorough explanation. I will be downloading the file, so your solution solves my problem.

Comment: @Kaiido thank you for your valuable insights

Answer (score 0):

I tried something like this...

```
var fs = require('fs');
var iconv = require('iconv-lite');

var str = '你好，世界';
var buf = iconv.encode(str, 'utf-32le');
fs.writeFileSync('test.txt', buf);
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to do this in a browser, not Node.js.